# How to get number of active processes and threads running using command-line?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, windows-server-2012, command-line-arguments

I should get the number of active processes and active threads running in my server or computer using command-line.. I don't want to list all the processes or threads running, I need them in numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using PowerShell, the following two commands will get that information:

Number of processes running:

```
(Get-Process).Count
```

Number of threads running:

```
(Get-Process|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Threads).Count
```

Comment: The command works perfectly on powershell but it doesn't work in cmd..Is there any specific command for cmd?

Comment: Run it in CMD as : `powershell "(Get-Process|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Threads).Count"`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use PowerShell for this.

To get a list of all active processes on the local computer, use this command.

```
Get-Process | Measure
```

[image: No of Active Processes]

You can also filter these results. For example, see the below code.

```
Get-Process winword, explorer | Measure
```

[image: No of Active Processes - Filter]

To get no of threads, run this command.

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Threads | Measure
```

[image: No of Threads]

---

To use these command in Command prompt, simply do this.

```
PowerShell -Command "Get-Process | Measure"
```

```
PowerShell -Command "Get-Process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Threads | Measure"
```

```
PowerShell -Command "Get-Process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Threads | Measure"
```

---

Resources
- [Get-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7)
- [Measure-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7)
- [Select-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7)