# What is the Windows equivalent of "ps aux | wc -l"?

Tags: powershell

I know Windows equivalent of "ps aux" is `tasklist` which works well on my win10

[image]

per [What is the Windows equivalent of "wc -l"?](https://superuser.com/q/959036/1100842) Windows equivalent of `wc -l` is `find /c /v ""`.

When I tried combine them together, I got

> FIND: Parameter format not correct

[image]

how do I use powershell to get the number of processes running on win10?

Comment: tasklist is not a powershell native applet, so to work with its output you need to parse text (just like you do with Linux), but that is not the preferred way to use an object oriented shell like powershell.  the native verb get-process lets you do all kinds of without parsing strings, like getting the number of processes.

Comment: This command would likely have worked in Command Prompt. PowerShell unfortunately is very different (not in a good way).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get number of active processes and threads running using command-line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1416905/how-to-get-number-of-active-processes-and-threads-running-using-command-line)

Comment: @DanielB not in a good way. In a great way. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(Get-Process).Count`

and, as a bonus:

`(Get-Process|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Threads).Count`

Run it in CMD (as an administrator) as : `powershell "(Get-Process|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Threads).Count"`

Example output:
[image]

Credit: [harrymc](https://superuser.com/a/1416912/1482432)

More info over at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 0):

`tasklist | Measure-Object -l`

and I still got my pipe, so I feel good ;)